# Coercion with NULL producing different results in javascript

Tags: javascript, equality, coercion

Just for fun,

In console, I did this:

```
Number(null);

Result comes 0
```

Then again I did this:

```
null == 0;

Result comes false;
```

Why is this strange behavior? I expected `true` based on the above example.

Answer (score 2):

It's just as simple as that `==` is not coercing `null` to a number. `null` is only `==` to `undefined` and itself. And `===` being strict about types doesn't coerce anything at all.

Comment: I understood the `===` part. But `==` is not coercing null to a number just like that, when it was already found to be zero in the beginning? Any special reason for not doing?

Comment: What do you mean by "*found to be zero in the beginning*"?

Comment: "*Any special reason for not doing?*" - no, none. That's just how it was designed to be. Probably because `null` is "nothing", and shouldn't compare equal to "anything" like a number (just like `null` behaves in most other languages).

Comment: I mean if I do `Number(undefined)`. It returns `NaN`. But in case of `null`, it returns `0`. So, if `null` is being treated differently here, then when comparing why coercion isn't happening for `null`

Comment: I don't really know, but - in a short moment of sanity - it was decided that neither `null` nor `undefined` are coerced at all into anything by `==`. Only because coercion is possible doesn't mean it has to be applied. For example, `null` could be coerced into a string as well - would you expect it to `== "null"`?